# InDesign: making an universal color change

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, swatches

I am working on a 144-page booklet. I need to make an universal color change throughout the document wherever the original color appears (text, strokes, etc).
I used to be able to trash the color in the color palette and I would be asked for a substitute. This doesn't happen anymore. Any other method?

Answer (score 1):

You can Find/Change by Object attributes (see the red circles below). Do it once for `Fills` (which will cover both text fills and object fills) and another time for `Strokes`. A more detailed article on how this works [here](http://indesignsecrets.com/findchange-objects-and-attributes-in-indesign-cs3.php).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remember that the "ghosted" trash icon may mean that the particular color may be used in graphic. So the color change may not work on that.

Comment: Great Tip! fort anyone reading, I made sure I copied the file and outlined all text so everything was an object... and then this worked flawlessly!